# Using NSNumberFormatter to format currency in output UILabel

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextfield, uilabel

```
NSNumberFormatter * fmt;
NSNumber          * n;

fmt = [ [ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ];
n   = [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10 ];

[ fmt setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ];
[ fmt setCurrencySymbol: @"$" ];
[ fmt setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ];

 // NSLog( @"%@", [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];

[ fmt release ]


-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
 {
double currency = [Amount1.text doubleValue] + [Amount2.text doubleValue]; 

SumCurrency.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", currency];


 }
```

How do I get the SumCurrency.text formated as 1,999 instead of 1999

Please help .. I am new to Objective - C , but my project is almost 95 % on interface builder .

I just need help with above code to implement .. Please I am struggling a lot with this .

Regards ,
Newbie.

Comment: The code you provided at the top *does* print '$1,999' (if you change n to 1999). Why aren't you using the formatter in your buttonPressed1 method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the answer .. But for anyone's future refernce

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
{
    double currency = [Amount1.text doubleValue] + [Amount2.text doubleValue]; 
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currency]];
    SumCurrency.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Converted:%@",numberAsString];  
}
```

Comment: The question you asked had an answer to it, u were doing it wrong

see my same answer to your question below

Answer (score 6):

```
NSNumberFormatter * fmt;
NSNumber          * n;

fmt = [ [ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ];
n   = [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10 ];

[ fmt setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ];
[ fmt setCurrencySymbol: @"$" ];
[ fmt setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ];

 // NSLog( @"%@", [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];

[ fmt release ];
```

use

```
SumCurrency.text = [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];
```

and you are done with it

Comment: is it give Problem in Future ??

Answer (score 1):

Note to person who asked and answered this question.

You said,

```
[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currency]];
```

but I think if your using an object of a class, like NSNumber, then you might want to put

```
[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:(NSNumber *) currency]];
```

See what I'm trying to say?