# How can I change the string (123456789) to string(123,456,789) In Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, format

a `string` have money value

```
NSString *money = "123456789";
```

I want print money like 123,456,789

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add commas to number every 3 digits in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233824/how-to-add-commas-to-number-every-3-digits-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

Replied by [Nik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692395/nik)

Use NSNumberFormatter.

Specifically

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2000000]];

[formatter release];
```

By default NSNumberFormatter uses the current locale so the grouping separators are set to their correct values by default. The key thing is to remember to set a number style.

Please refer to these links

1- [Link #one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406366/formatting-a-number-to-show-commas-and-or-dollar-sign)

2- [Link #Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233824/how-to-add-commas-to-number-every-3-digits-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Oneliners for the win

```
NSString *decNumberString =  [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[str integerValue]]
                                                     numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];   //here is money style... or or you can also set your other style
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123456789]];
```

and also refer following links...

1. [Objective-C: How to format string as $ Price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774982/objective-c-how-to-format-string-as-price)
2. [Using NSNumberFormatter to format currency in output UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384701/using-nsnumberformatter-to-format-currency-in-output-uilabel)

Comment: thank you very much. i coudn't find that link.